# append td to table row adds the tagname not the tag itself

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, append

I'm trying to append a td to each table row when a button is clicked
but it gives me the td as a plain text, not a tag

this is my js code, which selects each tr using jquery and then appends td to it

```
function addColmn() {
    $('tr').each(function(){
       this.append("<td id=" + maxId + " class='not-shaded'></td>");
       maxId++;
    });
}
```

and this is my html code

```
<table border="1">
        <button onclick="addColmn()">Add colomn</button>
        <tr>
            <td onclick="changeState(this);" id="cell1" class="not-shaded"></td>
            <td onclick="changeState(this);" id="cell2" class="not-shaded"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td onclick="changeState(this);" id="cell3" class="not-shaded"></td>
            <td onclick="changeState(this);" id="cell4" class="not-shaded"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$(this)` not `this` .

> `this` is the `DOM object`, whereas `$(this)` is the jQuery wrapper around same.
>
> When using `this`, you can call `DOM methods` on it, but not jQuery
>   methods. When using `$(this)`, you can call jQuery methods on it, but
>   not `DOM methods`.

```js
$(function(){


});

function addColmn() {
    $('tr').each(function(){
       var maxId = 0;
       var html = "<td id=" + maxId + " class='not-shaded'></td>";
       $(this).append(html);
       maxId++;
    });
}
```

```css
td {
   
   height:30px;
   width:30px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
        <button onclick="addColmn()">Add colomn</button>
        <tr>
            <td onclick="changeState(this);" id="cell1" class="not-shaded"></td>
            <td onclick="changeState(this);" id="cell2" class="not-shaded"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td onclick="changeState(this);" id="cell3" class="not-shaded"></td>
            <td onclick="changeState(this);" id="cell4" class="not-shaded"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you welcome shrouk happy to find an arabic developper :)